# Protocol Buffer - Send array of message to Client

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Below is the `message` I have created in my `.Proto` :

```
message ProductShippingReply {
  string id = 1;
  string shipping_mode = 2;
  double shipping_cost = 3; 
  int32 shipping_duration = 4;
}
```

in my Node.Js code I am trying to send an `Array` of this `message` back to the client, however the client receives an empty object. It works if I send only an instance of such `message`.

How do I send an `Array` of `Message` in PB?

Answer (score 0):

If you an only send this type of message you have to repetitively send a single message. If you do have control over the client you can modify the message you are sending. You can nest ProductShippingReply in a different proto message which defines the array.

```cpp
message ProductShippingReply {
  string id = 1;
  string shipping_mode = 2;
  double shipping_cost = 3; 
  int32 shipping_duration = 4;
}

message ReplyArray {
  repeated ProductShippingReply psr_array = 1;
}
```

Next you will fill a single ReplayArray object with multiple ProductShippingReply objects. This one ReplayArray object will then be communicated to your client.